# Mountain flags from Batman Begins

Tags: asia

This question may come up as a bit strange, but rest assured, it is about culture and symbolism.

During the first few minutes of Batman Begins (at 06:25), there is a scene of Bruce Wayne wandering to the top of the mountain (location unknown to me, but it is mountainous and it does have some Asian flavor to it). In this particular scene, Bruce reaches a plateau filled with a lot of flags (see the attached image):

[Flags](http://s9.postimage.org/edgqg433z/vlcsnap_2012_07_18_10h44m53s72.jpg)

My question is: **what do these flags represent?** I.e. is there a function to them, a cultural background, a custom, etc?

As a Europe-centeric historian, I'm completely clueless about these. Therefore, some explanation (and a few external links) would come in handy.

Comment: I don't see how flags in a movie that is set in a modern fictional near-future have anything to do with history.

Comment: @LennartRegebro - If the flags were made up, I'd agree. However, they do have cultural (and historical) relevance.

Comment: @T.E.D.: Then reasonably the question should be about Tibetan Prayer flags, not "The flags in Batman begins" which may have historical relevance or may not.

Comment: If he'd known they were Tibetan Prayer flags, he wouldn't be asking what the flags are...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They are tibetan buddhist prayer flags. More info [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portal%3aIndia/SC_Summary/SP_Tibetan_Prayer_Flag).

Comment: If you look carefully, it looks different than prayer flags.

Comment: @Sławosz: that may be true! These tibetian vertical prayer flags look like to be composed of several square-ish fabrics with prayers/mantras written on them, whilst the fabrics on the movie flags are just single long pieces. And the tops of the poles look different as well.

Comment: For me it is some [fantasy] war flag, because of top?

Comment: Some darchor flags have long single piece, some have multiple fragments. As an example for ones with a single piece, see [here](http://wanderlustandlipstick.com/blogs/debbysdepartures/2011/11/19/in-the-presence-of-prayer-flags/). Also the poles look similar in this image.

Comment: That's a fair enough explanation ;) . Thanks!

Comment: @Abhilash Could you enhance your answer with the comments please?  Right now its rather sparse and I'd like to vote it up.

Comment: If you read Hermann Hesse's Sihartha (as I was forced to in High School) those flags feature prominently. I was kinda jazzed to watch that movie and finally see what they looked like.